# How to close a specific webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and trying to figure out, how can I close an open webpage while keeping other webpages open. for example, I would like to open yahoo.com webpage as shown in the code bellow. Then I would like to close this yahoo.com page and open google.com page.

```
<?php

//To open yahoo.com page
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/"); 
</script>'; 

//How can I close the yahoo.com page and let the program keep running
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
sleep(10);

//To open google.com page
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://www.google.com/"); 
</script>'; 

echo "Done";

?>
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server side and client side.

Comment: This is really a JavaScript question. All your php is doing here is generating js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a JavaScript question.  The fact that you're echoing the script tags from PHP has no effect on the answer.

The return value of `window.open` is a handle to the window you've created.  If you store it, you can close it later:

```
var w = window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");  // Opens window with yahoo.com
w.close();                                     // Closes window with yahoo.com
```

[jsFiddle for the above code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/eLt5c/)

Note that (a) many browsers will block the popup, (b) it will close the window immediately after being opened.  If you want to sleep in between, use JavaScript's [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) method:

```
var w = window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");  // Opens window with yahoo.com
setTimeout(function() { w.close() }, 1000);    // Closes window with yahoo.com after waiting 1000 milliseconds
```

[jsFiddle for the above code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/eLt5c/1/)

Comment: Thank you for showing me with examples and all the details. I was able to solve it using javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function openWind()
    {
    myWindow=window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/","","width=1000,height=500");
    }

    function closeWind()
    {
    myWindow.close();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWind()" />
    <input type="button" value="Close 'myWindow'" onclick="closeWind()" />

    </body>
    </html>
```